# Monitor HTTP Requests made by iframe in node webkit

Tags: node.js, rest, http, node-webkit

I am developing a node webkit app which loads an iframe. Is there any module in nodejs which will allow me to track all the POST requests made by the iframe?

I have seen there are certain node modules which allow you to track requests made by the server, but I wont be creating a nodejs server as such and I would like to track the requests made by the iframe only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't monitor an iframe requests due to [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restrictions.
There are a few workarounds, maybe one of them might work for you

- If  you have access to the iframe code, see this question on [how to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
- You can load the content of the iframe using [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), then tracking it is easy as it is a part of the same page.
- what are you trying to track? there are few thing you can track. for examples s [Iframe Activity Monitor](https://github.com/aroder/IframeActivityMonitor) and [iframeTracker-jquery](https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery)